# Changing bounds of integration question; spot the mistake.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Suppose we wanted to compute $$\int \frac{1}{x^2 + x + 1} ~ dx.$$ One such way is to fix $c$ and let $x$ vary as bounds, thus we have that $$\int \frac{1}{x^2 + x + 1} ~ dx = \int_c^x \frac{1}{t^2 + t + 1} ~ dt = \int_c^x \frac{1}{(t + 1/2)^2 + 3/4} ~ dt.$$ We will now shift the integral by $1/2,$ so we have $$\int_c^x \frac{1}{(t + 1/2)^2 + 3/4} ~ dt = \int_{c+1/2}^{x + 1/2} \frac{1}{t^2 + 3/4} ~ dt.$$ The expansion theorem for integrals tells us that $$\int_{a}^b f(x + k) ~ dx = \frac{1}{c} \int_{ac + k}^{bc + k} f(x/c) ~ dx.$$ Using the aforementioned theorem, we have that $$\int_{c+1/2}^{x + 1/2} \frac{1}{t^2 + 3/4} ~ dt = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \int_{\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}c+1/2}^{\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}x + 1/2} \frac{1}{(3/4)t^2 + 3/4} ~ dt.$$ Factoring, we have $$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \int_{\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}c+1/2}^{\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}x + 1/2} \frac{1}{(3/4)t^2 + 3/4} ~ dt = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cdot\frac{4}{3} \int_{\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}c+1/2}^{\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}x + 1/2} \frac{1}{t^2 + 1} ~ dt.$$ This of course evaluates to $$\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3} \arctan\left( \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}x + \frac{1}{2} \right) + \text{constant}.$$ But then notice, taking the derivative of the expression before will not give us $1/(x^2 + x + 1).$ But, taking the derivative of $$\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3} \arctan\left( \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}x + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \right) + \text{constant}$$ does give us $1/(x^2 + x + 1).$ Where is the mistake?

Comment: $$ \int_{c+1/2}^{x+1/2}\frac1{t^2+3/4}\,\mathrm{d}t =\frac{\sqrt3}2\int_{\frac2{\sqrt3}c+\color{#C00}{\frac1{\sqrt3}}}^{\frac2{\sqrt3}x+\color{#C00}{\frac1{\sqrt3}}}\frac1{(3/4)t^2+3/4}\,\mathrm{d}t $$ since we substitute $t\mapsto\frac{\sqrt3}2t$, the limits go $t=c+\frac12\mapsto\frac{\sqrt3}2t=c+\frac12$, etc.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_{a}^b f(x + k) ~ dx = \frac{1}{c} \int_{ac + k}^{bc + k} f(x/c) ~ dx.$$ is wrong. It should be:
$$\int_{a}^b f(x + k) ~ dx = \frac{1}{c} \int_{a(c + k)}^{b(c + k)} f(x/c) ~ dx.$$

Comment: But notice that $$\int_a^b f(x) ~ dx = (b - a) \int_0^1 f[a  + (b - a)x] ~ dx,$$ and if you try to prove the left-hand side is equal to the right-hand side using your theorem, then it will not work.

Comment: I don't get what you mean.

Comment: Can you try proving that $$\int_a^b f(x) ~ dx = (b - a) \int_0^1 f[a  + (b - a)x] ~ dx,$$ using your theorem?

Comment: Well it is not something like theorem. It is just substitution. You sub $x=a+(b-a)u$ in LHS and you'll get the same result of RHS. Similar to my "theorem".